# How to convert a function into string?

Tags: python, string

Example function:

```
def my_function():if 9>8 print("Hello from a function") else print("Goodbye")
```

Expected Output:

```
String : """def my_function(): if 9>8 print("Hello from a function") else print("Goodbye")"""
```

Includes the reserved words (`def`,`if`,`else`) as well.

Comment: The definition of your example function is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).getsource()

As pointed out by @martineau (thx), your function had a *SyntaxError*. I reformatted your function and used a ternary to keep it single-line.

```py
    import inspect   

    def my_function(): print("Hello from a function") if 9>8 else print("Goodbye")

    print(inspect.getsource(my_function))
```

Output:

> def my_function(): if 9>8 print("Hello from a function") else print("Goodbye")

Comment: This does **not** work because the function definition is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @martineau ah yes you're right about the function syntax - corrected it

Comment: ...and I think it is something you should mention in your answer.